# Get current location using GPS in Android

Tags: android, gps

I'm working now in a project which i want to get the current location of user using gps. I have read many tutorial and tried to write the code. The code works well in the emulator. Every time i send the latittude and longitude using DDMS, the emulator will detect that. The main problem is that it doesn't work with the real devices. Although, the devices that i tried on it has internet access and the GPS is open.  I have added the required permissions to the manifest file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView lat;
TextView lon;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lat=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    lon=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    LocationManager lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll=new myLocationListener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, ll);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
   class myLocationListener implements LocationListener{

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(location!=null){
        double pLat=location.getLatitude();
        double pLong=location.getLongitude();
        lat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
        lon.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
}
```

the permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I need a help please.

Comment: You may use this library for a simpler location API: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation

Comment: @Marco W github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation not working properly, it's always returns 0.0 latitude and longitude.

Comment: @TejaDroid These two support issues should help you: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation/issues/3 and https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation/issues/4

Answer (score 2):

Try sth like this. You should remember that localisation stuff need to start GPS and it takes some time. In that class I fire localisation stuff with some delay to get results because GPS components should have time to start.

```
public class MyBestLocation {
    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
    //delay in seconds
    private int DELAY = 1;
    private Timer timer1;
    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationResult locationResult;
    private boolean gps_enabled = false;
    private boolean network_enabled = false;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result) {
        // 
        locationResult = result;
        if (lm == null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // checking weather providers are aviliable
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = lm
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        // 
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if (gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListenerGps);
        if (network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListenerNetwork);
        //----------------------
       // async executor method upgrade
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), DELAY*2000);
       // ----------------

        // 
       /* scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);*/
        return true;
    }

    // Timer for the latest location

    public static abstract class LocationResult {
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @author rafik991
     */
    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
            if (gps_enabled)
                gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (network_enabled)
                net_loc = lm
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            // if there are both values use the latest one
            if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {
                if (gps_loc.getTime() > net_loc.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);

                return;
            }

            if (gps_loc != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);

                return;
            }
            if (net_loc != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);

                return;
            }
//          locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }

    }

}
```