# How to get the Current Latitude and Longitude without Internet connection in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, latitude-longitude

I am creating an app related to location, so i need to get current latitude and longitude without having Internet Connection.

Please help me out. I am novice with Location Manager.
Suggestion appreciated.
Thanks Regards.

Comment: Using gps you can get current location without internet.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741632/get-current-location-using-gps-in-android

Comment: @officebrain This code works fine with Internet. I need to get Latitude and Longitude without Internet connection.

Comment: You can stop internet and go to out door area and get current location.

Answer (score 1):

There are Two ways to get the Location

1)Network provider

2)GPS Provider

for getting location through GPS  Provider(without Internet) Use `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` as mentioned in the below Code

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

if (locationManager != null) {

            location =locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();

                            }
                        }
```

and to know about the GPS status, whether enabled or not

```
boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

and for Removing Updated

```
if(locationManager != null){locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```